# Probability of two dice rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If two standard 6 sided dice are tossed what is the probability that a 3 is rolled on at least one of the two?

How do I solve this without listing out the possibilities?

Answer (score 4):

Compute the probability of NOT obtaining ANY $3$ at all, and subtract from $1$, to obtain the probability of getting *at least one* $3$.

On any die, the probability of not rolling a $3$ is equal to $\dfrac 56$. (That is, there are *five* numbers that are not $3$, each of which has a $\frac 16$ probability of being rolled.) This probability of not rolling a $3$ also holds for the second die, as well. We multiply the two probabilities, since each die's outcome is independent of the other's. This gives us that the probability of NOT obtaining a $3$ is equal to $\frac 56\cdot \frac 56$.

The complement of "not rolling any $3$" is "rolling at least one three." So, the probability of obtaining at least one $3$ is given by $$1 - \left(\frac 56\right)^2$$

Comment: 5/6 * 5/6 = 25/36 so the answer is 11/36?

Comment: How would I do this by finding the direct probability?

Comment: Yes, you're correct: the answer is $\dfrac {11}{36}$.

Comment: You can do the computation directly, but you'd have to count the probability where first die is $3$, add the  probability that the second die is $3$, and subtract the probability of obtaining two $3's$, since it will have been accounted for twice. $\dfrac 16 + \dfrac 16 - \dfrac 1{36} = \dfrac {11}{36}$

Comment: @amWhy: I am not the gambling type, but this is a sure bet! +1 :-)